# Copying all the DATA from SD card/USB pendrive

Tags: java, usb

I've been learning Java for a month now. I've already managed to code some very simple stuff like prime number generator and a simple calculator. Now i'd love to try working on something more complex.

Here's my idea - I'd love to make a program that can copy pictures from SD card or USB with a single click (something that my parents can use very easily to copy all their photos to a folder without my help)

I was brainstorming quite a bit about it and before i start i want to ask following questions:

**1.** Are there any inbuilt Java methods that can help me with the following task?

**2.** What are the other (non-beginner) Java features that i'd need to read about?

I want to start it from the scratch, make it simple at first and progressively add more features to practice and learn some more.

Any pointers or tips much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest doing this as a script.  The script can invoke java if you'd like to improve your java skills.  However, scripting languages can also copy/move files very easily.  If you choose java, read about file I/O, reading files, writing files, etc.

Here's a link for windows.  Not sure what your operating system is, but you could create an executable script on mac, linux, etc.

http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Batch-File